# Handling frequent simultaneous updates in real time

Tags: design, architecture, concurrency

I have seen similar questions and answers here but my situation is a bit different from those.
I am building an application which gives users infinite canvas space to draw something. The canvas space is open to all users and anyone can draw anywhere.

User will make drawings and whenever there is any change to any of the pixel, the changes get stored on server. If a user overwrites any other user's drawing, he will incur some penalty.

Now the problem: Multiple users can contest for the same space as the canvas is open. If user A draws on pixel X, any other user who draws after him on pixel X will get a penalty. But if multiple users are seeing pixel Y, which is empty, they all can try to draw something on that pixel. Now if I take the updates in sequential order, it might hurt the users. Because, I will save the first update and any consecutive update will be treated as overwrite. But for users, the pixel was empty.

One solution is to check the last update time for a pixel before updating and discard an update if the elapsed time is say less than 2 sec and give users a message for discarding their update. But this has two problems, the checking slows down the updates and second, hampers the user experience.

Is there any better strategy to handle this situation?

Comment: [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) ? Plus [Event Sourcing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591559.aspx) ? You'll probably need some kind of Queue Manager in order to serialize the updates and guarantee the enforcement of the penalty rule. The user experience will be bound to the network speed, though.

Comment: There really is not a "magical" way to solve this problem. You have to structure your game around such structural/temporal difficulties.

Comment: Maybe if you can detect such "race condition", then grab the first one, but don't penalize any change afterwards.

Comment: It's not 100% the same case, but Reddit for April 1st this year did a canvas for users to band together for, and wrote a blog on how they engineered the whole thing. There weren't penalties for overwriting, but I think the article is worth reading (good for a sense of scale, as well as good insights, and it's a good read too). [linky](https://redditblog.com/2017/04/13/how-we-built-rplace/)

Comment: Is the intent here, preventing overdrawing someone else's drawing a way to prevent vandalism on one's art, or is it actually a strategic decision as part of a larger gameplay?

Comment: @Delioth I've read their blog. It helped make some decision.

Comment: @LieRyan It's mostly to prevent vandalism on one's art. To maintain users' creativity on canvas.